# Rational and rationally chain connected surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, rational-curves

A projective variety $X$ over the complex numbers is rationally connected if two general points of $X$ can be joined by a rational curve in $X$, and rationally chain connected if two general points of $X$ can be joined by a chain of rational curves in $X$.

If $X$ is smooth these two notions are equivalent and if $X$ is a rationally connected surface then $X$ is rational. However, a cone over a smooth plane cubic gives an example of a rationally chain connected variety which is not rationally connected.

I would like to ask for an example of a surface $S$ admitting a morphism $S\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ whose fibers are connected chains of rational curves such that $S$ is not rational.

Comment: There is no such example over the complex numbers: apply Tsen's theorem to the morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ from a desingularization of $S$.  More generally, a normal complex projective variety is rationally connected if it admits a dominant rational transformation to a rationally connected variety whose geometric generic fiber is also rationally connected.  There are, however, counterexamples in positive characteristic, e.g., quasi-elliptically fibered surfaces.

Comment: I am not sure I got it. Let $\widetilde{S}$ be the desingularization of $S$. Then the morphism $\widetilde{S}\rightarrow S\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ might have disconnected fibers, and taking its Stein factorization we might get a morphism with connected fibers from $\widetilde{S}$ to a curve of positive genus. In this case $\widetilde{S}$ would not be rationally connected. Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: If $S$ is normal, then the fibers of that morphism are connected.  Are you asking for a counterexample that is not normal?  For any hyperelliptic curve $C$, just consider the surface obtained from $C\times \mathbb{P}^1$ by gluing $C\times\{0\}$ to itself via the hyperelliptic involution.

Comment: I reread your question, and now I see that you do not specify that $S$ is normal.  I give a nonnormal counterexample in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I did not specify that $S$ is normal because I thought that the hypothesis on the fibers of $S\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ would imply that $S$ is necessarily not normal.